# Convert HTML paragraph to newline

Tags: php, content-management-system, preg-replace, newline, preg-match-all

I'm improving my basic CMS for my blog. Today I added a new function which converts (double) newlines in the database to paragraph tags.

```
function nl2p($str) {
    $pattern = '/\n\n/';
    $replacement = '</p><p>';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
}
```

This works fine, except that I don't want to add any `<p>` tags within my `<pre>` tags. So I figured I'd expand my function to reconvert all those `<p>` tags to newlines, but it's not working. Any ideas on why?

```
function nl2p($str) {
    $pattern = '/\n\n/';
    $replacement = '</p><p>';
    $par = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);

    preg_match_all('/\<pre\>(.*?)\<\/pre\>/', $par, $pre_content);
    return preg_replace($replacement, $pattern, $pre_content[0]);
}
```

**Edit:** Since this seems like a hard nut to crack, perhaps I should add some context to my code. I'm using a [syntax highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) for displaying code in raw format on my blog. The highlighter is written in Javascript and makes use of the preformatted tags in HTML to display the code.

Also, my nl2p function above is a method of my blog class. The problem is that it places preformatted tags in raw format (i.e. visible) withing my preformatted tags.

**Edit 2:** Here is some sample code. First the original code from the database, then the formatted HTML code. An additional weird detail is that the last `</p>` in the code below is not actually visible in the source code. It comes after the closing pre tag.

```
<pre name="code" class="brush: javascript">
var data = [10, 20, 30];

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 500)
.attr("height", 500);

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d * 10; })
            .attr("cy", 50)
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d; })
            .style("fill", "red");</pre>

----------

var data = [10, 20, 30];<p></p><p>var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 500)
.attr("height", 500);

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d * 10; })
            .attr("cy", 50)
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d; })
            .style("fill", "red");</p>
```

Comment: Are you able to provide some test data?

Comment: Sure, see my second edit above. I suspect there's some bug in the syntax highlighter, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I found a different working solution at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php#97972

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your regexp is ok it should be:

```
return preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$pre_content[1]);//note the second element of the array [1]
```

Comment: Why? I want to return the full pattern, i.e. including the `<pre>` tags, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Converts a new-line delimited string (with embedded HTML PRE tags) to
 * HTML paragraphs, preserving the newline delimiters within the PRE.
 * @param string $str
 * @return string
 */
function pFormat( $str )
{
    $a = explode( "\n", $str );
    $out = array();
    $isPre = FALSE;
    $lastBlank = FALSE;
    for( $i = 0, $l = count( $a ); $i < $l; $i++ )
    {
        $line = trim( $a[$i] );
        if( empty( $line ) )
        {
            if( $isPre )
            {
                $out[] = "";
            }
            continue;
        }
        if( substr( $line, 0, 4 ) == '<pre' )
        {
            $isPre = TRUE;
            $out[] = $line;
            continue;
        }
        if( substr( $line, 0, 5 ) == '</pre' )
        {
            $out[] = $line;
            $isPre = FALSE;
            continue;
        }
        $out = '<p>' . $line . '</p>';
    }
    return implode( "\n", $out );
}
```

Comment: `split` is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: Thanks. Changed it to "explode".

Comment: Hm, I handed over `$test` to the function, which contains the string `'<p>Hello there</p>. Prepare for <pre>the pre tag</pre>.'` I get the following message in return:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in [the `return implode...` line].

Comment: Make sure that all assignments involving $out are like "$out[] = ...", except the first one. Based on what you provided for input, my function won't work for the following reasons: 1) <pre> and </pre> are on the same line, 2) the input has <p> and </p> in it already, so you'll get <p><p>....</p></p> in the output.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, this should convert double newlines to paragraph tags, except for those double newlines that are within preformatted tags:

```
$sourcestring="your source string";
echo preg_replace('#\n\n(?!((?!<pre>).)*</pre>)#is','</p><p>',$sourcestring);
```

Tested here, with a slightly modified pattern to account for the linefeed chars the tool includes: http://www.myregextester.com/?r=a24b18cf

Comment: Thanks, but this replaces newlines with paragraph tags, am I right? I'm trying to do other way around.

Comment: @Vienno, your question says you want to convert double newlines to paragraph tags, so yes, that is what my solution does!

Comment: Oh, wait. Your regex converts double newlines to paragraph tags, except for those paragraph tags that are within preformatted tags? Sorry if that is the case, all this regex gets me confused.

Comment: @Vienno, close, but not quite. It converts double newlines to paragraph tags, except for those double newlines that are within preformatted tags.

Comment: Sounds perfect. For some reason though, when I upload the new file I get a 500 internal server error. When I change it back, the page is visible again.

Comment: @Vienno, that's strange. Did you alter the code in any significant way?

Comment: No, I just put it into a function, making the sourcestring a parameter of that function, and passing in my blog posts. Shouldn't cause this behavior. I'll have to talk to my hosting company. Thanks for your help in the meantime.

Comment: @Vienno, I just noticed I set the pattern modifier to m, whereas I meant it to be i. That might fix it. If not, you might also try limiting the max length of the wildcard (which will limit the size of the <pre> contents that it can handle), eg to 5000 chars: '#\n\n(?!((?!<pre>).){,5000}</pre>)#is'

Comment: OK, using the max length version I have the page up and running again. Strangely though, the `<p>` tags are still there within the preformatted tags. I added some additional info in my original post, don't know if it has any relevance to the problem? I really appreciate your help.